# Git show files that were changed in the last 2 days

Tags: git, file, logging, git-log, fileupdate

How can I have a list with all the files that were changed in the last 2 days? I know about

```
git log --name-status --since="2 days ago"
```

but this will show me ids, dates and commit messages. All I need is the list of the file names which were changed.

Is that possible with git?

Answer (score 118, accepted):

```
git log --pretty=format: --name-only --since="2 days ago"
```

if some files duplicate in multiple commits, you can use pipe to filter it

```
git log --pretty=format: --name-only --since="2 days ago" | sort | uniq
```

Comment: you really want to use diff with the --stat modifier. This is not ideal.

Comment: As posted by AA `git diff --stat @{2.days.ago}` is shorter and cleaner.

Comment: @AdamDymitruk but why?

Comment: `git diff --stat @{2.days.ago}` doesn't show the full path and with long paths and multiple projects, there can easily be an overlap in paths, making the output unusable.

Answer (score 62):

```
git diff --stat @{2.days.ago} # Deprecated!, see below
```

Short and effective

### Edit

TLDR: use `git diff $(git log -1 --before=@{2.days.ago} --format=%H) --stat`

Long explanation: The original solution was good, but it had a little glitch, it was limited to the `reflog`, in other words, only shows the local history, because `reflog` is never pushed to *remote*. This is the reason why you get the `warning: Log for 'master' only goes back to...` in repos recently cloned.

I have configured this *alias* in my machine:

```
alias glasthour='git diff $(git log -1 --before=@{last.hour} --format=%H) --stat' 
alias glastblock='git diff $(git log -1 --before=@{4.hours.ago} --format=%H) --stat' 
alias glastday='git diff $(git log -1 --before=@{last.day} --format=%H) --stat' 
alias glastweek='git diff $(git log -1 --before=@{last.week} --format=%H) --shortstat | uniq' 
alias glastmonth='git diff $(git log -1 --before=@{last.month} --format=%H) --shortstat | uniq'
```

credits: answer below by @adam-dymitruk

Comment: This is really great.  Not sure why pretty-format got more votes.

Comment: @sevenfourk At least for me, working on a big project on a slow server, this solution is a lot slower than the pretty-format one. 
Also, doing that you get additional information, that may generate an extra job if you're parsing the output of this with any script. 
So, I upvoted the other one.

Comment: I had to change it to ` git diff --stat "@{2 days ago}"` to get it to work. (Maybe because I'm on Windows)

Comment: This does not work on Cocoapods/Specs because "warning: Log for 'master' only goes back to [Yesterday]"

Comment: Long paths are cut short and prefixed with `.../`, potentially ruining the ouptut.

Comment: Is there a reason to use`-1 --before` instead of `--after`?

Answer (score 3):

```
git log --pretty="format:" --since="2 days ago" --name-only
```

Comment: I find this command will only show the changes of last commit.

Answer (score 3):

Use the --raw option to git log:

```
$ git log --raw --since=2.days
```

See the --diff-filter part of the git log help page for the explanation of the flags shown in the --raw format. They explain what happen to the files in each commit:

```
   --diff-filter=[(A|C|D|M|R|T|U|X|B)...[*]]
       Select only files that are Added (A), Copied (C), Deleted (D),
       Modified (M), Renamed (R), have their type (i.e. regular file,
       symlink, submodule, ...) changed (T), are Unmerged (U), are Unknown
       (X), or have had their pairing Broken (B). Any combination of the
       filter characters (including none) can be used. When *
       (All-or-none) is added to the combination, all paths are selected
       if there is any file that matches other criteria in the comparison;
       if there is no file that matches other criteria, nothing is
       selected.
```

Comment: ty for the --diff-filter info details. good to know abut them from now on.

Answer (score 3):

You can do a diff of a version that's closest to 2 days ago with:

`git diff $(git log -1 --before="2 days ago" --format=%H).. --stat`

`--stat` gives you a summary of changes. Add `--name-only` to exclude any meta information and have only a file name listing.

Hope this helps.

Comment: combining two gits commends. That's very good to know. TY sir