# Git show list of files modified (but not yet committed) in the last X hours

Tags: git

I'm trying to see which of all the files I've modified but not yet committed, were modified in the last say 2 hours.

`git status` shows me the list of *all* the modified files, but I only want to see those modified recently.

I've found this question [Git show files that were changed in the last 2 days](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7499938/git-show-files-that-were-changed-in-the-last-2-days) but it seems to work for committed files only.

Can this be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Git does not store when a file was modified, only when it was committed. Instead, check the file's modification time on your filesystem using `find`.

```
find . -not -mmin +120 -not -path './.git/*'
```

`-not -mmin +120` looks for files which have NOT been changed at least 120 minutes ago. `-not -path './.git/*'` ignores the `.git` directory.

This will check all files in the directory. If you just want to check the ones Git knows about, filter the list from `git ls-files -m` on their modification times [using xargs](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-bsd-xargs-construct-argument-lists-utility/) and `find`.

```
git ls-files -m | xargs -I file find file -not -mmin +120
```

Or with `xargs` and [bash](https://linuxacademy.com/blog/linux/conditions-in-bash-scripting-if-statements/).

```
git ls-files -m | xargs -I file bash -c '(( $(date +%s) - $(stat --printf='%Y' file) < 7200 )) && echo file'
```

Comment: Thanks Schwern. Could you show how to use the `git ls-files` in combination with the `find` command? Right now the latter shows modified images and `*.pyc` files which I am not interested in.

Comment: The question is about **modified** files. `git ls-files -m`

Comment: @phd Thanks, fixed.

Comment: @phd Thank you.